# Creating a Linear Gravity Field in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

It seems that linear gravity field with vector method has been deprecated in Swift. There's a bunch of new SKFieldNode in this new language, but I can't seem to find one that resembles linear gravity. The property "direction" isn't even available in Swift. Maybe it can be done using this generic method customFieldWithEvaluationBlock but I'm not sure how. I'm new to SpriteKit.

So, how can we make the same physics effect in Swift?

Comment: It doesn’t look like it’s been deprecated, just… missing from the Swift SpriteKit API. You may want to [file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com) about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Swift 2 (part of Xcode 7), SIMD vectors are available to Swift, so API that uses them (such as [`linearGravityFieldWithVector`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKFieldNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKFieldNode/linearGravityFieldWithVector:), the new [GameplayKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GameplayKit/Reference/GameplayKit_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015199) and [Model I/O](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/ModelIO/Reference/ModelIO_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015421) frameworks, etc) is are now imported into Swift, too... no workarounds necessary anymore.

```
let field = SKFieldNode.linearGravityFieldWithVector(float3(1,0,0))
```

---

Previously... 
The `SKFieldNode` class method `linearGravityFieldWithVector` does this, but it's not available in Swift. In ObjC vector parameter uses the `vector_float3` type from the SIMD library, which uses special C compiler magic to make vectors that use SSE (on OS X / x86) or NEON (on iOS / ARM) hardware acceleration and pack nicely for sending to GPUs. That kind of voodoo doesn't currently exist in Swift, so any ObjC APIs that rely on it aren't imported into Swift.

For now, you can access those APIs from ObjC -- in a Swift project, you can make yourself a little ObjC wrapper function and expose it to Swift in your bridging header.

Comment: Okay, so I have a wrong assumption about it being deprecated. Good call on using objective c wrapper, I'll consider that as my work around. Thanks!

Comment: It doesnt recognize float3, or linearGravityFieldWithVector.  And I dont understand the part about how to get it to do so.  Objective c wrapper?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply linear gravity to all nodes you can try setting `physicsWorld.gravity`, it's a `CGVector`

Comment: Not all nodes. I want the gravity to apply only to specific region.