# Swift linearGravityFieldWithVector not available in XCode 6.4

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to create a linearGravityFieldWithVector with Swift 2.0 in XCode 6.4. According the [SKFieldNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKFieldNode_Ref/index.html) class reference, it is available in iOS 8.0. But XCode does not recognize it?
'SKFieldNode.Type' does not have a member named 'linearGravityFieldWithVector'

Suggestions?

This post implies it is available...
[Creating a Linear Gravity Field in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25558754/creating-a-linear-gravity-field-in-swift/25559517#25559517)

Comment: Swift 2.0 comes with Xcode 7 (beta), not with Xcode 6.4.

Comment: Sorry, Swift 1.2. Also the SKS editor allows me to add and configure a linearGravityFieldWithVector. Why am I not able from the code editor?